# Why is it difficult to calculate ΔS of the surroundings (said a teacher)?

Tags: thermodynamics

My chemistry teacher told me that the Gibbs Free Energy (G) function was created because determination of ΔS<sub>surroundings</sub>, and thus ΔS<sub>total</sub> was difficult, and we needed something better to explain spontaneity of a reaction.

However, I didn't exactly understand why it is so.

ΔS<sub>surroundings</sub> = $\frac{ΔH(surr)}{T}$

And we were told ΔH<sub>surroundings</sub> = -ΔH<sub>system</sub>

And ΔH<sub>system</sub> can be obtained experimentally.

So can't I simply say ΔS<sub>surroundings</sub> = $\frac{-ΔH(sys)}{T}$, maybe with this T being a different, yet deducible temperature ?

What exactly am I missing? And what is the true need for the G function anyway?

Comment: Good thinking. Now, using your reasoning, take $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\times\Delta S$, divide it by T, and what do you get?

Comment: Your teacher is right.  The surroundings are assumed to be vast—they need to be to act as a quasi-infinite heat bath, such that any heat flow into or out of them can be treated as reversible, because it changes the surroundings only infinitesimally.  Thus how would you directly measure $\Delta S_{surr}$?  Generally, you can't.  So you instead determine $\Delta S_{surr}$ *indirectly* from $\Delta H_{sys}$, which acts as a surrogate for $–T\Delta S_{surr}$.  And $\Delta G_{sys}$ is useful because it equals  $–T\Delta S_{surr}–T\Delta S_{sys} = –T\Delta S_{univ}$ => the condition for spontaneity.

Comment: Basically you've answered yourself

Comment: @Snijderfrey This may be a silly question, but what if the temperatures of the system and surroundings aren't equal? Then how can I get ΔS(surr) by dividing ΔH by T of the system?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment on your last sentence,  '... and what is the true need for the G function anyway ?'

It arose out  of experimental necessity. In the dim, distant past, it was naturally accepted that it was possible to convert all the heat of a reaction into work, so that $=-\Delta H$ was all that was needed to determine this. Many reactions were studied and the $-\Delta H$ for unmeasured reactions calculated, however, when these reactions were eventually measured serious discrepancies became clear, i.e. much larger than experimental error.

According to the first law the external work done must be equal to the heat loss of the system, *unless* some heat is given to or taken from the surroundings.  This was the point first clearly seen by Gibbs.

When an isothermal reaction occurs reversibly $T\Delta S$ is the heat absorbed from the surroundings, and if positive more work will be done than that given by the heat of reaction, and *vice versa*.

So the Gibbs function was not created as your teacher suggests but as a result of experimental data forcing us to consider how entropy affects reactions.